# C Stringize result of equation

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have read lots on stringizing macros, but I obviously don't quite understand.  I wish to make a string where the argument to the macro needs to be evaluated first.  Can someone please explain where I am going wrong, or perhaps how to do this better?

```
#define SDDISK          2     // Note defined in a library file elsewhere ie not a constant I know)

#define DRIVE_STR(d)    #d ":/"
#define xDRIVE_STR(x)   DRIVE_STR(x)
#define FILEPATH(f)     xDRIVE_STR(SDDISK + '0') #f

const char file[] = FILEPATH(test.log);

void main(void)
{
    DebugPrint(file);
}
```

The output is: "2 + '0':/test.log",
But I want "2:/test.log"

Comment: [Just drop the `+ '0'`](http://ideone.com/n9UBZP).

Comment: Why did you put the `0` if you don't want it?

Comment: Macros are expanded by the preprocessor. The preprocessor also does the stringizing. Afterwards, when the compiler sees the code, the `2` will be already be inside double-quotes. Hence, there is no need to add `'0'` to `2` to  convert it to the character `'2'`.

Comment: Haha, I didn't actually think of just dropping the '0'.   Makes sense just to stringize the 2 as is!  My existing code uses the +'0' to make the ascii character for '2' from the SDDISK macro so I guess I got blind sided by that!

Answer (score 0):

The C PREprocessor runs before the compiler ever sees the code.

This means that the equation will not be evaluated before it is stringified; instead, the preprocessor will just stringize the whole equation.

In your case just removing the `+'0'` will solve the problem as the value of `SDDISK` does not need casting to a char before it is stringified.

However, should you actually need to perform a calculation before stringizing you should either:

1. Use cpp's `constexpr`.
2. Complain to your compiler vendor that a constant expression was not optimized.
3. Use a preprocessor library to gain the wanted behaviour.